# Encrypt string in android and decrypt in node.js is not working

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I have to encrypt data in Android app and decrypt in Node.js.  But in web-end decryption is not working.

I need to Implement AES256 encryption and in web-end cryptoJS encryption library is used.

This is the string to be encrypted: `{"email":"jhon@gmail.com","device_type":"iOS","password":"123456","device_id":"14105DA4-CEE5-431E-96A2-2331CDA7F062","device_token":"B44777563552882EC3139A0317E401B55D6FC699D0AC3D279F392927CAF9B566"}`

And result should be

```
"U2FsdGVkX19hTYqle0GhmGoOK2oKGPfPXDkKsH8MdANABQROPiQ7hxnSA289rRT4fds5yZG4FX7BoTKqzV40NLIpeBoRJw6Uazax8kiKyxRYDUBPNpevD7vveDLoWekRL2cLZTV3S0gkynhL\/fKMg7BUFfT3Lt9BZeiFxYKZKD++ul5DG1isRycwG06l5ZgQJDwfyNAlRz7WbJXrevvCQPMagoCqrB4i49Mgj2ANMLFzUDyImhn9gX3PGrlzlY8xgzhg2oQfHF\/5USd5pqXswTRzVhGxUoUhNahf3pFZtbscr0AyvvE8ffF6ftRo4ZLYRt72aB9Br\/vqshXxr9VYuQ=="
```

Currenly I am using below code:

// Encrypt where jo is input, and query is output and ENCRPYTION_KEy is key

```
String secret = "LSC@SD2017@ps";
        byte[] input = new byte[0];
        String query = null;
        try {
            input = cipherText1.getBytes();

            byte[] cipherData = Base64.decode(cipherText1.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            byte[] saltData = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherData, 8, 16);

            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            final byte[][] keyAndIV = GenerateKeyAndIV(32, 16, 1, saltData, secret.getBytes("UTF-8"), md5);


            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] thedigest = md.digest(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc);

            byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
            int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
            ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);

             query = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);

            System.out.println("NEw code\n" + query);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In iOS code is perfectly working and they are using : https://github.com/etienne-martin/CryptoJS.swift

Please help me getting same output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CryptoJs Encryption is not working in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936706/cryptojs-encryption-is-not-working-in-android)

Comment: Hi @theLazyFinder.
Do you find the answer?

Comment: @EminenT can you post your answer?

Comment: @EminenT Did you find the solution?